# Error when reading ComboBox values within BackgroundWorker DoWork event

Tags: c#, winforms

When I acces Form controls within `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` event, it reads values from  **DatePicker** but not from **TextBox** or **ComboBox**

**Error:**

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmbProgram' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

[image]

**Code :**

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string strDate = dtpDate.Value.ToString();

        string strProgram = cmbProgram.Text;

    }
```

How does it read values from DataPicker (in a different thread)?

Is there any workaround to access Form Controls from `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` Event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
           {
                string strDate = dtpDate.Value.ToString();
                string strProgram = cmbProgram.Text;

           }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a control from a different thred.
The usual way of getting around that problem is to read the current value from the UI thread, and then pass the value to the second thread (or BackgroundWorker).

You can disable the check by setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls on the control class to false, but be advised you don't want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as an argument. For example:

```
backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

And grab the contents in the `doWork` with

```
string Item = e.Argument.ToString();
```